# Loss of connection with PostgreSQL database tier on Azure VM

Tags: postgresql, azure, virtual-machine, postgis, tatukgis

I have an Azure Virtual Machine running PostgreSQL 9.5 with Postgis installed and configured for external access (Internet).

But I'm having trouble accessing a layer that contains point geometries. The problem occurs when I access this layer via Tatuk Viewer (TatukGIS free software), after loading it on the map, it works normally, but if I stay around 5 minutes without doing any action using it, when I zoom in after that period, all points and data disappear, as if the layer were empty.

To return to normal state the table must be excluded from the project and included again

Comment: this is probably something you need to reach out to Tatukgis developers on.  Tatukgis is not open source and isn't a very active tag on StackOverflow (5 questions ever asked about it).

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the reply! I found out that I'm having errors in PostgreSQL, and that's why the layer information is disappearing, the error that occurs is:

ERROR: permission denied for schema public
STATEMENT: SELECT CAST(ST_EstimatedExtent('public','information_dae','geometry') AS TEXT) AS EXT

I disabled postgres user due to security account and activated 2 others, but they are returning invalid permission, could you help me?

Comment: It sounds like you need to grant your user USAGE on the public schema.

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <username>;